# seaborn kdeplot overlaid on catropy basemap

Tags: python, seaborn, cartopy

I have a kdeplot that I would like to overlay on top of a Google map basemap.

```
sns.kdeplot(dailyreport.long, dailyreport.lat,
             cmap="Reds", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.50)

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 12))
img = cimgt.GoogleTiles()
ax = plt.axes(projection = img.crs)
ax.set_extent([-76.849,-77.221,39.017,38.771])
ax.add_image(img, 12)
```

That above code results in:
[Above code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb4fX.png)

How can I get the heatmap to be on top of the Google map?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to use `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` to project the kdeplot on the map

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12, 12))
img = cimgt.GoogleTiles()
ax = plt.axes(projection = img.crs)
ax.set_extent([-76.849495,-77.22159,39.01713,38.77118])
ax.add_image(img, 12)
sns.kdeplot(dailyreport.long, dailyreport.lat,cmap="Reds", shade=True, shade_lowest=False, alpha=.50,transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.savefig('map1.png', dpi=100, bbox_inches = 'tight',pad_inches = 0)
```

[Final Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0a6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way that seaborn abstracts away the matplotlib interface, I don't think it can work with cartopy directly I'm afraid. [geoplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/index.html) claims to be a seaborn equivalent extension for cartopy.

One of geoplot's sample gallery is a kde heatmap which looks like what you're going for:

[image: Heatmap of Boston airbnbs]

https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_boston_airbnb_kde.html#sphx-glr-gallery-plot-boston-airbnb-kde-py